# Liquid lighting artifacts

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am currently working on a slime character splatting onto a branch using mantaflow fluid simulation. I am so close to my desired final look, but the last problem I have is that the lower half of the simulation had bizarre, jittery lighting. I am mostly confident that this comes from the automatically generated geometry from the fluid mesh, but I don't know how to fix the issue. I have tried increasing the Upres factor and Particle Radius, but while the smooth shaded model is a bit more refined, the lighting issues persist.
If anyone has done slow-moving liquids before and seen this issue, how did you fix it?
Here is the Vimeo link: https://vimeo.com/492565125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, increasing frame steps fixed the issue and made the whole thing look a bit smoother.